# how handle click in a first tab in PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a `PagerSlidingTabStrip` and need to do something special only in case of a click on first tab in PagerSlidingTabStrip. This code has to be run even if the first tab is visible.

I do not need `pageChangeListener` as it will be triggered only when the page will be changed.I want click listener on first tab view in `PagerSlidingTabStrip`.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to implement page change listner like below**

```
     viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position==0){

               // Do whatever you want here for first tab click
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: i just want to handle the click on first tab  even if the tab is visible.

Comment: " check this if it works "             mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    if ( event.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    int pos= viewpager.getCurrentItem();
    if (pos==0) {
     
     //DO Task here
    }
    }
    return false;
   }
  });

Comment: the child view consumes the touch, so it is not in control of pagerslidingtabstrip

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to edit the lib.

in `PagerSlidingTabStrip.java` you need to put some extra code for click listner e.g.

```
private OnTabClickListener onTabClickListener = null;

//interface with ontabclick method
public interface OnTabClickListener {
    public void onTabClick(View v,int position);
}

//init interface using setOnTabClickListener method.
public void setOnTabClickListener(OnTabClickListener onTabClickListener){
    this.onTabClickListener = onTabClickListener;
}
```

and after putting this code you need to edit `addTab`  method of `PagerSlidingTabStrip.java` file e.g.

```
private void addTab(final int position, View tab) {
    tab.setFocusable(true);
    tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //editation
            if(onTabClickListener != null) {
                onTabClickListener.onTabClick(v,position);
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////

            pager.setCurrentItem(position);


        }
    });

    tab.setPadding(tabPadding, 0, tabPadding, 0);
    tabsContainer.addView(tab, position, shouldExpand ? expandedTabLayoutParams : defaultTabLayoutParams);
}
```

now in your main code.

```
tabs.setOnTabClickListener(new PagerSlidingTabStrip.OnTabClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabClick(View v,int position) {
            // do stuf here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reflection to get the the private methods.
my code:

```
        try {
        Field tabsContainerField = PagerSlidingTabStrip.class.
                getDeclaredField("tabsContainer");
        tabsContainerField.setAccessible(true);
        LinearLayout tabContainer = (LinearLayout) tabsContainerField.get(mSlidingTabLayout);
        View child = tabContainer.getChildAt(0);

       //now i can do anything with view.
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i know this is not very good approach one of the way. if anyone knows then please share.